# Is there a source for this story of the seven brothers?

Tags: sources-mekorot, agada-stories-legends, story-identification

This is part of the story:

"There were once seven brothers, the sons of one woman, in the city of Tzippori. They were wealthy, but one day they went to a certain city in the land of India. They were not welcomed there, and they said: Let us go and hide in one of the caves. They went and hid in a cave, and a miracle occurred, and a carob tree and a water spring were created for them. They would remove their clothing and sit in sand up to the their necks. Each one of them would wear one of his garments, and the other would cover himself with his hair. In this manner, they lived in the cave for twelve years."
"Then they said: The time has come for us to leave the cave. They emerged and saw a man plowing and planting trees. They asked him: What are you doing? He said to them: I am planting trees. They said to him: Let us ask you something: If you plow and plant during the day and do not plow and plant during the night, what will happen to the trees that you plant? He said to them: They will die and wither." ............

Comment: Has many elements in common with this story from Shabbat 33b https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shabbat.33b.6?lang=en

Comment: Yes, Also with The II Book of Maccabees 7.                                      https://www.sefaria.org/The_Book_of_Maccabees_II.7.1?lang=bi @JoelK

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Haroune and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Why do you suspect there may be a Jewish source for this story? Where did you find this story?

Comment: Where did you read this story?